# How to drop minutes in R?

Tags: r

I have a DateTime object in R.

```
tempDateTime<-as.POSIXct("2017-07-13 01:40:00 MDT")

class(tempDateTime)
```

[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

I would like to drop the minutes from the DateTime object. ie have "2017-07-13 01:00:00 MDT"

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to round to the nearest hour, or round down / up exclusively?

Comment: Truncate to get starting hour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Base R

```
trunc(tempDateTime, units = "hours")
# "2017-07-13 01:00:00 AEST"
```

---

This works because the `round` function in base R has a method to handle `POSIX` objects.

From `?round.POSIXt`

> Round or truncate date-time objects.

---

As @Thelatemail points out, this returns a `POSIXlt` object, so you may want to wrap the result in `as.POSIXct()` again.

---

Another note, `POSIXct` is an object that stores the number of seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00" (the Unix epoch).

```
as.numeric(tempDateTime)
# 1499874000
```

So the manual way to round-down the hours would be

```
as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(tempDateTime) / 3600) * 3600, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Comment: Note that this returns a `POSIXlt` object, not a `POSIXct`.

Comment: I haven't thoroughly tested it, by why not just wrap the `trunc` in `as.POSIXct()` to keep the initial format?

Comment: @thelatemail - ha, yeah, I'm over-thinking it!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)

> floor_date(tempDateTime, "hour")
[1] "2017-07-13 01:00:00 PDT"
```

Comment: s/a function/several functions in different packages/