# Change Timestamp in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I added a column to record the timestamp in R by using the following code

```
data$Date <- Sys.Date()      2018-08-10 18:06:21
```

This pastes a time-stamp with the current system date and time.

However, I want to set the time in the time-stamp to `00:00:00`.

I tried using `strptime` and replacing the text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean `Sys.time()` - `Sys.Date()` doesn't return a date + time. Also, you want `?trunc` (`?trunc.POSIXt` to be exact)

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I just want to change the `18:06:21` portion of the timestamp to  `00:00:00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325631/round-a-posix-date-posixct-with-base-r-functionality or maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745396/how-to-drop-minutes-in-r/45745554

Comment: The `round` function truncates the time-stamp. I intend to have `00:00:00` as well

Comment: Nope, that's just how it prints to the screen, it's still stored as a datetime with 00:00:00 after rounding. You can use `format()` around the date if you need it all to be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this , one way is to `format` your time part from `Sys.time()` to the required time.

```
data$Date <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
```

`Sys.time` returns current system date and time

```
Sys.time()
#[1] "2018-10-10 05:12:56 GMT"

format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
#[1] "2018-10-10 00:00:00"
```

---

Or if you want to use `Sys.Date` you can wrap it in `as.POSIXct`

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
```